# Why is the ENTRY() in my linker script not being set to the . = <address> section?

Tags: c++, c, linker

I am trying to relocate the entry point of a statically-linked binary I am building to a fixed value, so it can be loaded into that area of memory by a bootloader and jumped into with a function pointer dereference.  Here is the loader script I am using:

```
ENTRY(main)
SECTIONS
{
        . = 0x0000000000200000;
        .text : {
                *(.text)
                . = ALIGN(8);
        }
        .data : {
                *(.data)
                *(.rodata)
                . = ALIGN(8);
        }
        __bss_start = .;
        .bss : {
                bss = .; _bss = .; __bss = .;
                *(.bss);
        }
        end = .; _end = .; __end = .;

  .preinit_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  }
  .init_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.init_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .fini_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.fini_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  }
}
```

Here is the command line I am using for the final link:

```
...
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -mcmodel=large -fPIC -T src/controlix.ld -Wl,--no-relax -static -nostdlib -static-libgcc
...
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(shell find bin/ -name "*.o") -o $(TARGET_OBJ)
```

(Details of the rest of the build system omitted for brevity, I don't think any of it is pertinent)

So, I am assuming that when I look at the resultant controlix.o binary, I should see the main() symbol located at 0x200000, right?  Wrong:

```
$ nm bin/controlix.o |grep main
000000000021d0c6 t _GLOBAL__sub_D_main.cpp
000000000021d087 t _GLOBAL__sub_I_main.cpp
000000000021cef1 T main
0000000000256e11 t _ZL8eiremainPtS_P7LDPARMS
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> I should see the main() symbol located at 0x200000, right?

No. Imagine how many things have to be done before main is called. Libraries have to be initialized, constructors and destructors called (C++), on many systems .bss zeroed and .data initialized + many other things I do not remember now.

The `main` is the entry point of the `C` program but is not (in almost all known implementarions) the entry point of the executable file.

if you want **your** function to be called first, place it in the separate segment and amend the linker script

```
    .text : {
            *(.beforetext) 
            . = ALIGN(8);
            __text_start = .;
            *(.text)
            . = ALIGN(8);
    }
```

```
extern unsigned __text_start;

void __attribute__((section(".beforetext"))) myEntryFunc(void) 
{
 ....

 ((void (*)(void))(&__text_start))(); // call the original executable entry point
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ELF, the `ENTRY` directive defines `main` as the entry poin in the ELF file header with no effect on the address of `main`.

To force `main` to be at the start of the text segment, one technique is to put `main` in its own section and then positioning this section before the `.text` section.

With recent GCC and Clang, you may use `__attribute__((section(".main"))__` or `[[gnu::section(".main")]]` in a variable or function declaration to set the section.